# how to show amazon interstitials when app starts (android)

Tags: java, android, ads, amazon-appstore

I was wondering how to display amazon interstitial Ads right when the app starts on android devices.

I have tried...

`AdRegistration.setAppKey(APP_KEY);
        this.interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        this.interstitialAd.loadAd();
        this.interstitialAd.setListener(this);`

under OnCreate but the ad won't appear

Answer (score 0):

Make a launcher activity by declaring it as launcher in manifest in on create show your interestial

Make a handler and use postdelayed to start your main activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // do not set contentView 
        Your Interestial logic goes here  


      //set up a handler to start main activity   
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {     

                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,HomeActivity.class);             
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

        }

    }, 4000);
```

}

Comment: could I clarify that I want to show it after a splash screen

Comment: Simply setContentView in your launcher as splash screen after than modify Handler.post to Handler.postDelayed http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29  http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-run-runnable-thread-or-ui-thread.html